# How can I remove "Chart of accounts" from the search bar for my permission set?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, navision, dynamics-business-central

I'm trying to remove "Chart of accounts" from the search bar in Business Central for a permission set

What I did is giving only indirect execute permissions to the page 16 "Chart of accounts" and also for the tabledata 15.

I'm still being able to search for "Chart of accounts". I can't access it as it gives me a permission error from another object:

[image]

I really don't know what else I can try or look

How can I completely remove access to "Chart of account" for that specific permission set so it's not accessible neither available to find in the search bar?

Answer (score 0):

On the new page, you can do it by set AccessByPermission properties. This property cannot be changed by page extension. It means that is not possible to do it.